# How to hook delete breakpoints command in gdb

Tags: gdb

GDB supports the hook command function. For example, when GDB executes the `delete` command, the user-defined hook command can be executed:

```
define hook-delete
  printf "hook a delete command.\n"
  # do something
end
```

But how to hook `delete breakpoints`?

After verification, execute the `delete breakpoints` command, knowing that the above `hook-delete` function will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

I already know the answer by querying the GDB manual.

The GDB manual reads as follows:

> You can hook a multi-word command by adding hook- or hookpost- to the last word
> of the command, e.g. ‘define target hook-remote’ to add a hook to ‘target remote’.

So, the function to hook `delete breakpoints` can be defined like this:

```
define delete hook-breakpoints
  printf "hook a delete breakpoints command.\n"
  # do something
end
```